# Merge multiple select statements and group them

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge

I am having trouble to find an efficient solution to my problem. I think this is a fairly common issue, that is why I am asking it out here.

Here is the problem.

Let says I have multiple selects such as the following ones :

SELECT CREATE

| date | num_created |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 10 |
| 01-02-2021 | 2 |
| 01-04-2021 | 13 |

```
SELECT Update
```

| date | num_update |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 14 |
| 01-02-2021 | 2 |
| 01-03-2021 | 9 |

```
SELECT Delete
```

| date | num_delete |
| --- | --- |
| 01-02-2021 | 2 |
| 01-05-2021 | 40 |

I want to have this final output

```
Final output
```

| date | num_created | num_update | num_deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 10 | 14 | 0 |
| 01-02-2021 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 01-03-2021 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| 01-04-2021 | 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 01-05-2021 | 0 | 0 | 40 |

*I can't assume that any table has all the dates or have matching dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want count grouped by days:

```
select
    tbls.date,
    sum(tbls.num_created) as num_created,
    sum(tbls.num_updated) as num_updated,
    sum(tbls.num_deleted) as num_deleted 
from (
    select date, num_created, 0 as num_updated, 0 as num_deleted from tbl_create
    union all
    select date, 0 as num_created, num_updated, 0 as num_deleted from tbl_update
    union all
    select date, 0 as num_created, 0 as num_updated, num_deleted from tbl_delete) as tbls
group by tbls.date
```

Please don't abuse "with statement" when it is not needed (as seen in the other answers).

Edit - extra simple query:

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_dml_statement') is not null drop table #tmp_dml_statement 
    select date, num_created, 0 as num_updated, 0 as num_deleted
    into #tmp_dml_statement
    from tbl_create
    union all
    select date, 0 as num_created, num_updated, 0 as num_deleted
    from tbl_update
    union all
    select date, 0 as num_created, 0 as num_updated, num_deleted
    from tbl_delete
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, I don't find it particularly clean but it works. Please don't abuse with statement, is it to avoid performance issue or for cleanliness?

Comment: For cleanliness. With should be used in recursive query or complex non-recursive query to replace subqueries or for example improve the readability of your code of view. In my example you can see derived query (or you can use select into #tmp statement to simplify even more - example added into answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can perform full outer join between the tables and case statement to choose the date as below (Assume 3 tables/queries as a, b, c):

```
With temp as
    (
    select case when a.date is not null then a.date else b.date end as date,num_created,num_update from a full join b on (a.date=b.date)
    ),
    temp1 as
    (
    select case when temp.date is not null then temp.date else c.date end as date,num_created,num_update,num_delete from temp full join c on (temp.date=c.date)
    )
    select * from temp1;
```

Comment: @waldo404 Can you please check ?

Comment: Yes this works! I did something else to solve my problem but I like the way you solve it! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

assume the tables are:

```
tbl_create(dt, num_created) 
tbl_update(dt, num_updated)
tbl_delete(dt, num_deleted)
```

start with a (temporary)table that contains all dates from the 3 source tables:  all_dates

then (left outer) join the counters from the 3 source tables.

note: 'union' removes duplicates, no need to worry about that (in contrast to 'union all')

note: coalesce(a,b)    returns the first non-null parameter, so you have zeroes rather than 'null's

```
with all_dates(dt) as (
   select dt from tbl_create
   union
   select dt from tbl_update
   union
   select dt from tbl_delete
)
select all_dates.dt
     , coalesce(tbl_create.num_created,0)    --   
     , coalesce(tbl_update.num_updated,0)
     , coalesce(tbl_delete.num_deleted,0)
from all_dates 
  left outer join tbl_create on all_dates.dt = tbl_create.dt
  left outer join tbl_update on all_dates.dt = tbl_update.dt
  left outer join tbl_delete on all_dates.dt = tbl_delete.dt
```

Comment: Hmm, so you get a list of the dates first and then left join to all the tables, I am wondering in term of performance what will happen if I have a lot of data, to query the table twice? But still thanks for taking time anwsering my question!

Comment: depends on the databse you are using, but you will be surprised how good query optimizers are at optimizing your query.